# Azure DevOps pipeline integration with Databricks + how to print Databricks notebook result on pipeline result screen

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, databricks, azure-databricks

Am trying to integrate Azure Databricks within DevOps pipeline and used following URL: https://menziess.github.io/howto/run/databricks-notebooks-from-devops/

1. At Azure Databricks, created a job on top of my notebook
2. Used a separate VM with preinstalled Databricks-CLI and set it as a self-hosted pool agent
3. Prepared a YAML script in pipeline, which calls the above databricks job on my self hosted agent pool

My Pipeline and databricks jobs are executing successfully.

But I want to extract the output generated by notebook inside pepeline and print on console. In this way anyone can trigger the pipeline by passing their parameters and view the result on console screen.
Notebook mostly returns output as table data (e.g. select * from table).

Could someone help me with this.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If yes, you could accept it as an answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. If not, please let us know if you would like further assistance

Answer (score 0):

we can try to use the powerShell script to set the result as the variable, then we can output the data to a file. This can be a work around. At present, in the pipeline we can not pass their parameters and view the result on console screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the cli command `databricks fs cp` in a final step in the DevOps pipeline to copy the data to the agent, then print it out using an appropriate tool.